# How to access pref pane bundle?

Tags: objective-c, nspreferencepane

How do we access Pref Pane Bundle for Mac OS app???
I have placed images and other resources inside the pref pane bundle, but I am not able to get the path using:
    NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tick" ofType:@"png"];

where tick.png is present in the resources folder in NewPrefPane.prefPane

Answer (score 7):

> [NSBundle mainBundle]

returns the NSBundle for the System Preferences application since that is the one that is actually running your pane.

Use the **bundle** method if you just need it in your NSPreferencePane class:

```
[self bundle]
```

Use **bundleForClass** elsewhere in your pane code:

i.e.

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class] pathForResource:@"tick" ofType:@"png"];
```